# Apache Commons Email v1.1 change timeout time

Tags: java, playframework, apache-commons

I am creating an application with play framework in java. I have the following code to send an email when you register:

```
SimpleEmail mail = new SimpleEmail();
mail.setHostName(ConfigFactory.load().getString("mail.hostname"));
mail.setSmtpPort(ConfigFactory.load().getInt("mail.port"));
mail.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(ConfigFactory.load().getString("mail.username"), ConfigFactory.load().getString("mail.password")));
mail.setDebug(true);
mail.setMsg("Test");
mail.setTLS(true);
mail.setFrom("emailhere");
mail.addTo(email);
mail.setSubject("Activate your email");
mail.setMsg("message");
mail.send();
```

Now when the mail server can't be reached it takes quite some times before it gives an error. I want to shorten this time so the user doesn't have to wait as long. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mail.setSocketConnectionTimeout` (connenction timeout) and `mail.setSocketTimeout` (read timeout). Example for setting both to 10 seconds:

```
mail.setSocketConnectionTimeout(10000);
mail.setSocketTimeout(10000);
```

Comment: Method's don't exist.

Comment: 1.1 is a very, very old version. Upgrade to a newer version and those methods already exists

Comment: I can't find a newer version. I'm looking on: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-email/commons-email/

Comment: Not sure if I'm mixing two different libs, but is not this you are looking for? http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-email%7C1.4%7Cjar

Comment: Ah now I found it. Thanks. Its [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-email/) they moved it under the org.apache.commons